# Transformation increasing variance of bounded random variable

Tags: probability-theory, variance

> Consider a random variable $X:\Omega\to[0,1]$ and the transformation to a Bernoulli variable
>   $$
> T(X) = \begin{cases}1 &\text{if }X\geq m\\ 0 &\text{otherwise}\end{cases}
> $$
>   where $m$ is the median of $X$.
>   Show that ${\it Var}(T(X))\geq {\it Var}(X)$.

Remarks:

- Intuitively, the variance should increase when weight is "squeezed to the sides". But it's been tricky to prove.
- If $P(X=m)=0$, then ${\it Var}(T(X)) = 1/4 \geq {\it Var}(X)$. But I need the general case where $P(X=m)\not=0$.

Edit:
It turns out that this conjecture is false. I posted a more general version here [Transformation that increases variance of bounded random variable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1998658/transformation-that-increases-variance-of-bounded-random-variable)

Comment: Does $X$ have a density $f$?

Comment: @JimmyR. The second bullet excludes that.

Comment: @drhab Yes, it was vice-versa, so you are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result does not hold.

For a simple counterexample, assume that $P(X=0)=x$, $P(X=x)=\frac12$ and $P(X=1)=\frac12-x$, for some fixed $x$ in $(0,\frac12)$.

The median of $X$ is (unique and) equal to $x$, thus $T(X)$ is Bernoulli with parameter $P(X\geqslant x)=1-x$ and its variance is $x(1-x)$.

On the other hand, $E(X)=\frac12(1-x)$ and $E(X^2)=\frac12(1-x)^2$ hence the variance of $X$ is $\frac14(1-x)^2$.

One sees that $\mathrm{Var}(X)>\mathrm{Var}(T(X))$ for every $x<\frac15$... and that $\mathrm{Var}(X)<\mathrm{Var}(T(X))$ for every $x>\frac15$.

Comment: Cool, I did not expect that. Do you think there could be another choice of threshold $m$ such that the result holds? For example $m=E[X]$ instead of $m$ the median of $X$.

Comment: Did you try to check this new proposal on the example in my answer? Why not?

Comment: $m=E[X]$ avoids the problem of your counterexample, since then the weight located at $x$ is shifted to 0 rather than 1 for small $x$. So it's not obvious that $m=E[X]$ doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: I posted a more general version of the question here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1998658/transformation-that-increases-variance-of-bounded-random-variable @Did