# Transformation that increases variance of bounded random variable

Tags: probability-theory, variance

> Consider a bounded random variable $X:\Omega\to[0,1]$. Does there always exist a transformation $T:[0,1]\to \{0, 1\}$ such that $V(T(X))\geq V(X)$?

Remarks:

- $T(X)$ will be a Bernoulli variable with the weight squeezed to the sides. Intuitively, it should be possible to do this in a way so that the variance increases.
- A possible transformation would be
  $$
  T(X)=\begin{cases}1 &\text{if } X\geq m \\ 0 &\text{otherwise}\end{cases}
  $$
  with $m=E[X]$.
- I initially thought that choosing $m$ the median of $X$ would solve the problem. However, it only works for continuous variables. A counter example for discrete variables can be found here [Transformation increasing variance of bounded random variable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1984230/transformation-increasing-variance-of-bounded-random-variable)
- I would give partial credit for showing that there exists a constant $c>0$ such that for all $X:\Omega\to[0,1]$ there exists $T:[0, 1]\to\{0,1\}$ such that $V(T(X))\geq c\cdot V(X)$.

Comment: "However, it only works for continuous variables." Does it? How do you know? "A counter example for discrete variables can be found here " Yes, and this counterexample can most probably be adapted to give a continuous counterexample.

Comment: @DId There is no continuous counterexample. He probably knows it by the obvious fact, that $Var(X)=1/4$ can be achieved by the above transformation, if there exists $m$ such that $P(X<m)=\frac12$ and $P(X\ge m)=1/2$. And $Var(X)=1/4$ is the maximum possible variance for any variable whose support is in $[0,1]$.

Comment: @JimmyR. To repeat my first comment, note that the OP states that the transformation $T_{\mathrm{med}}:X\mapsto T_{\mathrm{med}}(X)=\mathbf 1_{X\geqslant\mathrm{med}(X)}$, where $\mathrm{med}(X)$ denotes a median of $X$, "works for continuous (random) variables", that is, if I understand correctly, that $\mathrm{Var}(T_{\mathrm{med}}(X))\geqslant\mathrm{Var}(X)$ for every continuous random variable $X$. When you say that "There is no continuous counterexample", are you asserting that this statement is correct?

Comment: @Did Yes, it is reasonably easy to prove that for any variable $X:\Omega\to[0,1]$, $V(X)\leq 1/4$ (using $E[X^2]\leq E[X]$). And when $X$ is continuous, $T_{med}(X)\sim Ber(1/2)$, so $V(T_{med}(X)) = 1/4$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider first the intermediate transformation
  $$
    T_\lambda(X) =
    \begin{cases}
      \lambda X & \text{if } X \leq \mu\\
      X & \text{otherwise}
    \end{cases}
  $$
  moving the leftward values closer to 0, and leaving the rightward
  elements unchanged.

Let $\mu_\lambda = E[T_\lambda(X)]
  = \lambda\int_{X\leq\mu} X dP + \int_{X> \mu} X dP
  = \mu - (1-\lambda)\int_{X\leq \mu} X dP
  = \mu - (1-\lambda)a$ with
  $a = \int_{X\leq \mu} X dP\in[0,1]$.

The variance
  $V(T_\lambda(X))
  = \int_{x \leq \mu} (\lambda x -\mu_\lambda)^2 dP
  + \int_{x> \mu} (x - \mu_\lambda)^2 dP$.
  Taking the derivative
  \begin{align*}
    \frac{\partial}{\partial \lambda} V(T_\lambda(X))
    &= \frac{\partial}{\partial \lambda} \int_{x \leq \mu} (\lambda x -\mu_\lambda)^2 dP
      +\frac{\partial}{\partial \lambda}  \int_{x> \mu} (x - \mu_\lambda)^2 dP\\
    &= \int_{x \leq \mu} \frac{\partial}{\partial \lambda} (\lambda x - \mu_\lambda)^2 dP
      +  \int_{x> \mu}\frac{\partial}{\partial \lambda} (x - \mu_\lambda)^2 dP\\
    &= \int_{x \leq \mu} 2(x-a)(\lambda x - \mu_\lambda) dP
      + \int_{x> \mu}2(-a)(x - \mu_\lambda) dP\\
    &= 2\int_{x \leq \mu} x(\lambda x - \mu_\lambda) dP
      -2a\left(\int_{x \leq \mu} (\lambda x - \mu_\lambda) dP
      + \int_{x> \mu} (x - \mu_\lambda) dP\right)\\
    &= 2\int_{x \leq \mu} x(\lambda x - \mu_\lambda) dP
      -2a\int (T_\lambda(x) - \mu_\lambda) dP\\
    &= 2\int_{x \leq \mu} x(\lambda x - \mu_\lambda) dP
  \end{align*}
  Thus, the derivative $\frac{\partial}{\partial \lambda} V(T_\lambda(X)) \leq 0$,
  since $\mu_\lambda\geq \lambda\mu$ implies that
  $\lambda x - \mu_\lambda \leq \lambda (x - \mu) \leq 0$ for $x \leq \mu$.
  Therefore $V(X) = V(T_1(X)) \leq V(T_0(X))$.
  We have thereby shown that the variance increases if we
  shift the leftmost ``half'' of $X$ to 0.
  We can now apply the same argument to $-T_0(X)$,
  getting $V(T_0(X)) = V(-T_0(X))\leq  V(T_0(-T_0(X))) = V(T(X))$.